# Silverlight and HTML5 ... Can they coexist?

Tags: .net, silverlight, html, windows-8

Heard that with windows 8, microsoft will prvoide HTML5 extensions for all their .Net APIs... http://www.i-programmer.info/news/89-net/2654-making-sense-of-microsoft-net-and-html5.html

If so, will it be the end of silverlight?

PS. You guys can vote to close if this discussion is irrelevant.

Comment: A good post about Silverlight's future. http://www.lhotka.net/weblog/Silverlight6DoesnrsquotMatter.aspx

Comment: This is quite a debate... http://www.zdnet.com/blog/microsoft/will-there-be-a-silverlight-6-and-does-it-matter/11180

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Petr Abdulin answer.
And my opinion about Silverlight is that platform is strong, powerful and crossplatform (please, don't tell about *nix platform - theres is less than 1% desktop PC that have Linux), it has many-many features for gaming and enterprize solutions. It will be supported for another ten years (in .net world, WinForms in similar situation - its not develoing in MS, but supported by MS; but who cares - Winform is still alive). If I would like to create client-server application with thin client, I select Silverlgiht.

Comment: @Raynos: Where on Earth did you get a figure of 1%? More like 70-75% based on actual research e.g. http://riastats.com/

Comment: @HiTechMagic I'm impressed microsoft managed to quietly push out silverlight to 65% of the web, by hard coupling it to their OS. Now if only they could quietly upgrade every IE browser to IE9. Maybe then we can start solving real problems.

Comment: @Raynos: Given you expertise *is in other areas*, is it wise to put down Silverlight & MS quite so vehemently? I am glad to see you deleted your "on only 1% of browsers" comment. Quoting blatant falsehoods will not strengthen your arguments :)

Comment: @Raynos: Another beauty of how the web works is that anyone can express a personal opinion to the world... I only ask that you not distort facts to support your personal opinions ;) Thanks.

Comment: @HiTechMagic I understand. Your saying I'm not a .NET expert, thus I should shut up.

Comment: @Raynos: Yep, just like I do not go around slating COBOL, Linux etc. `"If you haven't got something nice to say, say nothing"` :)

Comment: 2 @Raynos, I agree that 1% isn't real ratio for Desktop Linux. The real ratio is 1.65% (by statistics from http://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php )

Answer (score 1):

The answer is *Yes* in both cases: yes you can, and yes [very probably](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/microsoft/will-there-be-a-silverlight-6-and-does-it-matter/11180) it's the end of Silverlight *as cross platfrom solution*. Other than that, Silverlight is there and will be for some long time. If crossplatform is not major factor (but it's usually a very big plus in general) then there is not reason to worry.

Comment: SilverLight was never a cross platform solution.

Comment: @Raynos Silverlight (currently) works on Windows and Mac.

Comment: That's not cross platform. What about *unix

Comment: define: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossplatform  "A cross-platform application may run on as many as all existing platforms, or on as few as two platforms."

Comment: Cross platform generally means it works on all major platforms. That's like saying "My websites is cross browser, it works on IE6 and IE7". Which is clearly pedantic, out of context trolls.

Comment: @Raynos On the contrary! Crossplatform generally means, again: "A cross-platform application may run on as many as all existing platforms, or on as few as two platforms." Is Wikipedia is not authoritative enought?

Comment: @PetrAbdulin yes and every unix application I use is cross platform, it runs on at least two different distributions of unix. Now take these trolls elsewhere.

Comment: @Raynos - Your analogies are false. To use the browser one, it would be like saying "My website is cross-browser, it works on IE and Firefox (but not Safari)". Yes, SL doesn't work on every OS platform. But it does work on more than one. That makes it cross-platform by definition. You're free to disparage SL all you like, but your argument that it isn't cross-platform is simply invalid.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName I find it misleading marketing bullshit to abuse the term cross-platform like that. Technically your correct, except I simply don't tolerate marketing bullshit.